# ExecuteScript(document.getElementById('form') in Webview2(C++) return null or some jQuery like string

Tags: c++, getelementbyid, webview2

I'm used webview2 executeScipt to access DOM but have some issue.

html document is loading completed and then below c++ code called.
only getElementById function not working, return null,
but outerHTML is well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="internalWrapper">
    <div id="container" class="lightTheme">
    <div id="form_header"></div>
    <div id="form" ctrltype="CT_FORM" class="formGrid" container="true"></div>
    <div id="form_footer"></div>
    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```cpp
webview->ExecuteScript(_T("document.documentElement.outerHTML", hCallback) // OK, return full html code 
webview->ExecuteScript(_T("document.getElementById('form')", hCallback)    // return null
```

I changed html file to very simple html and
changed api to getElementByClassName()
but return null.

Comment: You call the `getElementById()` before the page is ready so at the time of execution it is null.

Comment: Thanks comment. But If document is not ready, why documentElement.outerHTML could get full Html code?

Comment: `documentElement.outerHTML` gets just a text, that is not yet processed by DOM builder.

Comment: sorry.. what do you mean DOM builder still processing .. means Nativigation does not completed?

Comment: documentElement.getElementById('form').outerHTML is work well. 
thanks.